# .NET configuration tools in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

This [site](http://www.grimes.demon.co.uk/workshops/fusWSTwo.htm) explains about the .net configuration tool, but I can't find one in Windows 7.

Where is the .net configuration tool in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net framework 3.0 and above does not have .net config tool, and Windows 7 comes with .net 3.5

You won't find that tool in Windows 7

Comment: Any reason for that? Is there replacement tool for it?

Comment: I guess it is not needed anymore, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I posted another question about this - http://superuser.com/questions/199134/caspol-and-net-configuration-tool , Thanks.