# caspol and .NET configuration tool

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I see that .NET configuration tool is not provided anymore with .NET 4.0 (Windows 7), but this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186212(VS.80).aspx) explains about the tool 'caspol' and .NET Framework Configuration tool (Mscorcfg.msc).

How can I use caspol.exe to generate configration XML file? This site explains about .NET configuration tool to generate the config XML file automatically. I want to know how to do that with caspol.exe.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <gcConcurrent enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <publisherPolicy apply="yes" />
     <probing privatePath="bin;bin2" />
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And, what is Mscorcfg.msc? How can I run/use this tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you don't need `caspol.exe` or `Mscorcfg.msc`.  There were some [big changes in Code Access Security(CAS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103(v=vs.100).aspx) in .NET 4.0 which eliminated the need for the two tools.

You can find out more about `Mscorcfg.msc` snap-in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc(v=vs.90).aspx).  It is basically a nice GUI interface to the `caspol.exe` Code Access Security policy editor command-line utility.

Comment: Link to the Snap-in is broken, do you know where to find it now?

Comment: @nunespascal, I've updated both links.